# Is my below method to solve $xy'' -y'= x^n$ correct?

Tags: integration, ordinary-differential-equations, boundary-value-problem

I have tried to solve the following ODE:   $$xy'' -y'=3 x^2$$ using homogenous solution and particular solution such that $y=y_p+y_h$, $y_h$ is the solution of $xy'' -y'=0$ which is defined as known to Euler-Cauchy equation by $y_h=c_1 x^2+c_2$ , Now I assumed the particular solution as : $y'_p=3 x^2$ means that $y_p=x^3$ yield to the general solution of $xy'' -y'=3 x^2$ being defined as  $y=y_p+y_h=c_1 x^2+c_2+x^3$, Now I have tried to generalise the non-homogenous equation as :$xy'' -y'= x^n$ and  $n$ is a positive integer taking $y'_p= x^n$, In my computation using wolfram alpha for many values of $n$ I saw that $y_p$ takes the following form :$\displaystyle y_p=\dfrac{x^{n+1}}{ (n^2-1)}$ , Now Is really what I have conjuctred true ? and is it  a valable method to take $y'_p=x^n$ ?

**Addedndum**:I have a wrong typo in my particular solution form  I edited it to $n^2-1$ in denominator look the below example .According to the particular solution form we have $y'_p =f(n) x^n$ with $f(n)=\dfrac{1}{n-1}$ this what I want to prove how this come up ?

**Example**: The general solution of  $xy'' -y'=x^{21}$ is :$y(x)=c_1 x^2+c_2+\dfrac{x^{22}}{440}$
Then finally the general solution of $xy'' -y'= x^n$ become as $$y(x)=c_1 x^2+c_2+\dfrac{x^{n+1}}{ (n^2-1)}$$

Answer (score 2):

\begin{align}
& xy'' -y' = ax^n \\
\text{by division on }x^2\qquad & \frac{xy'' -y'}{x^2} = ax^{n-2} \\
\text{reform the LHS}\qquad & \left(\frac{y'}{x}\right)' =ax^{n-2} \\
\text{assuming $n \neq 1$, integration wrt }x\qquad & \frac{y'}{x} =\frac{a}{n-1}x^{n-1} +b \\
\text{by multiplication with }x\qquad & y' =\frac{a}{n-1}x^{n} +bx \\
\text{assuming $n \neq -1$,  integration wrt }x\qquad& y = \frac{a}{(n^2-1)}x^{n+1} +\frac{b}{2}x^2 +c
\end{align}

Answer (score 2):

You have a second order linear ODE in terms of $y$. However, your ODE is first order in terms of $z=y'$. These are solved by the method of integrating factors. We have
$$z'-x^{-1}z=3x$$
the integrating factor $I$ is

$$I=\exp\int -x^{-1} dx=x^{-1}$$

Now multiply by $I$ to get

$$x^{-1}z'-x^{-2}z=3$$
and this we can write as
$$\left(x^{-1}z\right)'=3$$
$$x^{-1}z=3x+2C$$
$$z=3x^2+2Cx$$
$$y=x^3+Cx^2+D$$
If you want $x^n$ instead of $3x^2$ on the RHS then you will get

$$y=\frac{1}{\left(n+1\right)\left(n-1\right)}x^{n+1}+Cx^2+D, n\geq0 , n\neq 1$$

by the same method.

Answer (score 1):

$$xy'' -y'=0$$
$$x^2y'' -xy'=0$$
Is indeed Cauchy-Euler differential equation. Try $y=x^m$ gives:
$$m(m-1)-m=0$$
$$m^2-2m=0$$
$$\implies m=2,m=0 $$
$$y_h=c_1+c_2x^2$$

---

For the second differential equation:
$$xy'' -y'= x^n \,\,;n \ge 0\text { and } n \ne 1$$
$$y_p=ax^{n+1}$$
or $y'_p=ax^n$
is correct too. It gives:
$$a=\dfrac 1 {n-1}$$
$$\implies y_p=\dfrac {x^{n+1}} {(n^2-1)}$$

For $n=1$ the formula wont work and
$$xy''_p-y'_p=x$$
$$\left ( \dfrac {y'_p}{x} \right)'=\dfrac 1x$$
$$\dfrac {y'_p}{x}=\ln x$$
$${y'_p}=x\ln x$$
$$ y_p=\dfrac {x^2}2\ln x-\dfrac 12\int x \, dx$$
$$\implies y_p=\dfrac {x^2}2\ln x-\dfrac {x^2}4$$
Finally the solution is:
$$y=c_1+c_2x^2+\dfrac {x^2}2\ln x$$

Comment: yes it can't work for n=1 because a become undeterminated at n=1

Comment: Yes exactly you have to solve it with another method @zeraouliarafik

Answer (score 0):

$$xy''-y'=x^n$$

---

$$xy''-y'=0\Rightarrow y=c_1x^2+c_2$$
$$\therefore y_c=c_1x^2+c_2$$

---

$$y=y_p+y_c$$
$$y=y_p+(c_1x^2+c_2)$$
$$x(y_p''+2c_1)-(y_p'+2c_1x)=x^n$$
$$xy_p''-y_p'=x^n$$
This shows that indeed your solution for $y_c$ is correct. Now to verify $y_p$ just sub in

---

$$y=c_1x^2+c_2+\frac{x^{n+1}}{(n+1)^2-1}$$
$$y'=2c_1x+\frac{(n+1)}{(n+1)^2-1}x^n$$
$$y''=2c_1+\frac{n(n+1)}{(n+1)^2-1}x^{n-1}$$
you will see that:
$$xy''-y'=2c_1x+\frac{n(n+1)}{(n+1)^2-1}x^n-2c_1x-\frac{(n+1)}{(n+1)^2-1}x^n=\frac{(n+1)(n-1)}{(n+1)^2-1}x^n$$
so this solution for $y$ does not appear to be correct